# Linux multiprocessors support

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, multithreading

I am reading the following [paper](https://vldb.org/pvldb/vol15/p21-skiadopoulos.pdf). In the paper, the authors argue that Unix/Linux "has struggled for a decade to support multiprocessors in a single node" in the last paragraph of the first page. I don't understand what this sentence actually means. Why is it so hard to support multiprocessors in Unix/Linux? Is it the architecture of Unix/Linux that makes that hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the “Age” paragraph a few lines above your quote, the paper gives four references:

> Linux has struggled for a decade to
> fully leverage multi-cores [14, 20, 22, 34].

Those references are, respectively:

- [Scaling in the Linux Networking Stack](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/scaling.html) (part of the kernel documentation), which describes various techniques to improve networking performance on multiprocessor systems;
- Silas Boyd-Wickizer, Austin T. Clements, Yandong Mao, Aleksey Pesterev,
  M. Frans Kaashoek, Robert Morris, and Nickolai Zeldovich. 2010. An Analysis of
  Linux Scalability to Many Cores. In *Proceedings of the 9th USENIX Conference on
  Operating Systems Design and Implementation* (Vancouver, BC, Canada) *(OSDI’10)*.
  USENIX Association, USA, 1–16.
- Chansup Byun, Jeremy Kepner, William Arcand, David Bestor, William Bergeron,
  Matthew Hubbell, Vijay Gadepally, Michael Houle, Michael Jones, Anne Klein,
  et al. 2019. Optimizing Xeon Phi for Interactive Data Analysis. In *2019 IEEE High
  Performance Extreme Computing Conference (HPEC)*. IEEE, 1–6.
- Jean-Pierre Lozi, Baptiste Lepers, Justin Funston, Fabien Gaud, Vivien Quéma,
  and Alexandra Fedorova. 2016. The Linux Scheduler: A Decade of Wasted Cores.
  In *Proceedings of the Eleventh European Conference on Computer Systems* (London,
  United Kingdom) *(EuroSys ’16)*. Association for Computing Machinery, New York,
  NY, USA, Article 1, 16 pages. https://doi.org/10.1145/2901318.2901326

I’m not familiar with all four references, but the first hints at limitations in networking, and the last gives examples of scheduler bugs which cause available cores to remain idle even though there are runnable threads waiting.

So the answer to your question about the meaning of the comment seems to be that there have been documented instances of less-than-ideal (to put things mildly) performance in the Linux kernel when run on systems with multiple processors (or cores).

This is a matter of opinion, but I think the main reasons multiprocessor support has proven difficult (in both UNIX and Linux) is that concurrency is difficult for many humans to reason about, and that both systems started out as non-concurrent systems and had support for concurrent architectures added *without* a major redesign — in Linux, using the infamous Big Kernel Lock at first. I don’t think the question of whether the *architecture* of UNIX or Linux itself introduces fundamental problems in correctly supporting concurrent platforms has been settled, at least in symmetric multiprocessing systems.

(You might find [It's Time for Operating Systems to Rediscover Hardware](https://youtu.be/36myc8wQhLo) interesting.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I watched "It's Time for Operating Systems to Rediscover Hardware" you shared. The speaker argues that Linux assumes the ccNUMA architecture. If so, why are people able to use devices such as GPU, which has a different address space than CPU, in Linux?

Comment: Timothy Roscoe doesn’t argue that the Linux assumptions make things impossible, but rather that the current way of thinking about operating systems is incomplete. GPGPU handling is an example of this: the Linux kernel controls the “main” CPU cores in your system, and the main memory in your system, but feeding the GPGPU and transferring data to and from the GPU’s memory is largely left to programs using them (through CUDA etc.).